# How do event triggers affect program flow?

Tags: .net, timer

If my program is in the middle of doing some operation in Function A and a timer tick event is triggered that calls Function B, what happens to my program flow? Does it immediately stop what is happening in A and jumps to B? If so, does it return eventually to where it was in A? Does it finish A first, then go to B? Does it do each on a separate thread? Something else entirely?

I want to use a timer for something, but my understanding of the way it works makes it seem like it can wreak havoc with a program's predictable control flow. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are mistaken. Timers in .NET are not interrupts, what it does do is dependant on the timer you are using but the two general behaviors are thread specific timers and thread pool based timers.

For a thread specific timer like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in WinForms or `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` in WPF or `System.Timers.Timer` if you set the `SynchronizingObject` if Function A is running on the UI thread and the timer for Function B fires Function B will not run till after Function A finishes.

For thread pool based timers like `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` without the `SynchronizingObject` set if Function A is running and the timer for Function B fires Function B will be started on a new thread and both Function A and Function B will be running at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the SynchronizingObject property or thread pools (reading up on it now, but I've always gotten lost every time I waded into the topic of threading). I'm actually doing this in a console app, using System.Timers.Timer so I take it from your second paragraph that they will each run separately, without any one of them affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to move, you can use sleep to stop timer for A until it completes B and then continue , otherwise if u have multi threaded app., both can run simultaneously.